# Apply Callable to NDArray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, callable-object

I am new to Python and I have done a fair share of just trying things to see if it works. In this case, when I apply a Callable to an NDArray, I get a result, just not what I expected.

```
from typing import Callable
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np

callable : Callable[[float], Tuple[float, float]] = lambda x : (x , x + 1)
array : np.ndarray = np.asarray([0, 1, 2, 3])
result = callable(array)
print(result)
```

I expected (or rather hoped) to get an iterable of tuples where each tuple is the output of the callable applied to a float. What I got was a tuple of arrays:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

What is actually happening? (Why should I expect the results I actually got?)

Comment: That `lambda` function does not iterate on `array`.  The `x` inside the function is `array` itself, the whole thing.  It just returns a tuple, the same as if you did `result=(array, array+1)`.  Using the `lambda` does not change that behavior.  Your `lambda` is just another syntax for doing `def foo(x): return x, x+1`.

Comment: If you want to iterate, you'll have to iterate. `callable(x)` is just calling your function on object `x`. It doesn't "apply" anything in the sense that you want

Comment: I think you want `map(callable, array)`.

Comment: Also, your typing annotation is just misleading.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments, the typing annotation for `callable` was misleading and the lambda was just applied to the array itself - the same as if I did `result=(array, array+1)`. Nothing mysterious going on. Thanks for the help.